# Outlook 2010 having issues after disk space issues?

Tags: windows-7, email, microsoft-outlook-2010

So I had an issue with a log file going out of control eating up disk space.  It seems that any email that came in during said time is now "locked down" by Outlook.

All of these emails are in my inbox folder.  I cannot move or delete them.  I can forward them so I have taken care of the ones I want by reforwarding them and then storing.  So now I have like 100 emails I need to delete but I can't.

Get one of two errors:

"Cannot move the items."

"The operation failed.  The messaging interfaces have returned an unknown error.  If the problem persists, restart Outlook."

I have taken care of the disk space issues and restarted computer and outlook many times.  Next step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `SCANPST.EXE` (or scanost.exe for offline cache) to *attempt* to repair any corruption to the mailbox.  Beyond that, the only answer I've ever gotten from Microsoft is "erase the file and start over."

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\SCANPST.EXE" (or similar based on your version)

Comment: That worked.  Backed up and scanned.  Took about 15 minutes to go through and about a minute to repair.